# Running spark-submit with --master yarn-cluster: issue with spark-assembly

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running Spark 1.1.0, HDP 2.1, on a kerberized cluster. I can successfully run spark-submit using --master yarn-client and the results are properly written to HDFS, however, the job doesn't show up on the Hadoop All Applications page. I want to run spark-submit using --master yarn-cluster but I continue to get this error:

```
appDiagnostics: Application application_1417686359838_0012 failed 2 times due to AM Container
for appattempt_1417686359838_0012_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000 due to: File does not
exist: hdfs://<HOST>/user/<username>/.sparkStaging/application_<numbers>_<more numbers>/spark-assembly-1.1.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
```

I've provisioned my account with access to the cluster. I've configured yarn-site.xml. I've cleared .sparkStaging. I've tried including --jars [path to my spark assembly in spark/lib]. I've found [this question](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201412.mbox/%3CF6BBCA02033DF14F87A3F0D2553EB0AA5844AA13@DEWDFEMB18C.global.corp.sap%3E) that is very similar, yet unanswered. I can't tell if this is a 2.1 issue, spark 1.1.0, kerberized cluster, configurations, or what. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Running into the same issue.  Did you get it to work?  Would appreciate any pointers.  Thanks.

Comment: Seems that upgrading to a more recent version of Spark helped. I'm using Spark 1.3 now, but it was working just fine with 1.2.1. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is probably because you left `sparkConf.setMaster("local[n]")` in the code.

Comment: Gah! It was so obvious! Thanks, that saved me from a big headache.